How to avoid using a method with a parameter of type object when using an interface which will be used in a collection
So I want to try to avoid using object in my methods to make things more type safe and avoid boxing/unboxing but I'm not sure what the best way to solve this is. Using generics is not ideal for this situation here since there will be a collection of the type (so it cannot have generic params). I'm thinking a solution that uses double dispatch might work here (i.e. visitor pattern).
The general setup is something along the lines of:
public class ServiceCheck(IList<IServiceCheckResult> results)
{
    public IList<IServiceCheckResult> Results = results;
}

public interface IServiceCheckResult
{
    IResultValidator Validator { get; }
    object? GetRawValue();
    void SetRawValue(object? value);
}

public class ServiceCheckResult(IResultValidator validator) : IServiceCheckResult
{
    private object? rawValue;
    public IResultValidator Validator { get; } = validator;

    public object? GetRawValue()
    {
        return rawValue;
    }

    public void SetRawValue(object? value)
    {
        rawValue = value;
    }
}

public interface IResultValidator
{
    public bool Validate(object? value);
}

public class StringValidator : IResultValidator
{
    public bool Validate(object? value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value);
    }
}

public class DoubleValidator : IResultValidator
{
    public bool Validate(object? value)
    {
        return (double)value > 0;
    }
}

public class EnumValidator : IResultValidator
{
    public bool Validate(object? value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
...

and the usage will be something like this:
var serviceCheck = new ServiceCheck(new List<IServiceCheckResult>
{
    new ServiceCheckResult(new DoubleValidator()),
    new ServiceCheckResult(new StringValidator()),
    new ServiceCheckResult(new EnumValidator())
});

serviceCheck.Results[0].SetRawValue(1.0);
serviceCheck.Results[1].SetRawValue("This is a test");
serviceCheck.Results[2].SetRawValue(MyEnum.None);

foreach (var result in serviceCheck.Results)
{
    var rawResult = result.GetRawValue();
    result.Validator.Validate(rawResult);
}


if you haven't abandoned the question, I'd like you to check if my answer is enough for your use case

Since the instance implementing IServiceCheckResult will be aware of the value it can get/set I think we can change the IServiceCheckResult to have a parameterless Validate() to save us one unnecessary boxing. We can also add generic methods to the interface and a Type property to support type checking and using the generic methods instead of the non-generic methods.
public interface IServiceCheckResult {
    object? GetRawValue();
    void SetRawValue(object? value);
    bool Validate();

    Type Type { get; }
    T? GetTypedValue<T>();
    void SetTypedValue<T>(T? value);
}

To make things easier we can also introduce another generic interface in the middle providing default method implementations for the non-generic interface. This allows us to make the IResultValidator interface generic too which will save us from boxing there.
public interface IServiceCheckResult<T> : IServiceCheckResult {
    T? GetValue();
    void SetValue(T? value);
    public IResultValidator<T> Validator { get; }


    // EIMIs for non-generic Interface
    Type IServiceCheckResult.Type => typeof(T);
    bool IServiceCheckResult.Validate() => this.Validator.Validate(GetValue());

    object? IServiceCheckResult.GetRawValue() => GetValue();

    void IServiceCheckResult.SetRawValue(object? value) {
        if (value == null) {
            ThrowIfSettingNullToNonNullableValueType();
            this.SetValue(default(T)); // really null
            return;
        }

        if (value.GetType() != typeof(T)) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Wrong type of value. Expected {this.Type}, but got {value.GetType()}");
        }

        this.SetValue((T)value);
    }

    [return: MaybeNull]
    TBase IServiceCheckResult.GetTypedValue<TBase>() {
        if (typeof(TBase) != typeof(T)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Wrong type. Expected {this.Type} but got {typeof(TBase)}");
        }

        T? value = GetValue();
        if (value == null) {
            return default(TBase);
        } else {
            var castedValue = Unsafe.As<T, TBase>(ref value);
            return castedValue;
        }
    }


    void IServiceCheckResult.SetTypedValue<TBase>([AllowNull] TBase value) {
        if (typeof(TBase) != typeof(T)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Wrong type. Expected {this.Type} but got {typeof(TBase)}");
        }

        if (value == null) {
            ThrowIfSettingNullToNonNullableValueType();
            SetValue(default(T)); // we can't really do (T)null
        } else {
            var castedValue = Unsafe.As<TBase, T>(ref value);
            SetValue(castedValue);
        }
    }


    private void ThrowIfSettingNullToNonNullableValueType() {
        var thisType = typeof(T);
        var isValueType = thisType.IsValueType;
        var isNullableValueType = thisType.IsGenericType &&
            thisType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);

        if (thisType.IsValueType && !isNullableValueType) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot set null for non-nullable value types");
        }
    }
}

I've also added some runtime-type checking with meaningful exceptions messages (still can be improved). Because of all the default interface implementations we don't have much to do in the concrete ServiceCheckResult class which we can make generic.
public class ServiceCheckResult<T>(IResultValidator<T> validator) : IServiceCheckResult<T> {
    T? _value;
    public IResultValidator<T> Validator => validator;
    public T? GetValue() => _value;
    public void SetValue(T? value) {
        _value = value;
    }
}

Now the validator interface and validator classes are generic too:
public interface IResultValidator<T> {
    public bool Validate(T? value);
}

public class StringValidator : IResultValidator<string> {
    public bool Validate(string? value) {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}

public class DoubleValidator : IResultValidator<double> {
    public bool Validate(double value) {
        return value > 0;
    }
}

public class DoubleNullValidator : IResultValidator<double?> {
    public bool Validate(double? value) {
        return (value != null && value > 0);
    }
}

public enum MyEnum {
    Default,
    None
}

public class EnumValidator : IResultValidator<MyEnum> {
    public bool Validate(MyEnum value) {
        return value != MyEnum.None;
    }
}

And finally I've adapted your usage code to showcase what we can do now:
var serviceCheck = new ServiceCheck(new List<IServiceCheckResult>
{
    new ServiceCheckResult<double>(new DoubleValidator()),
    new ServiceCheckResult<string>(new StringValidator()),
    new ServiceCheckResult<MyEnum>(new EnumValidator()),
    new ServiceCheckResult<double?>(new DoubleNullValidator())
});

serviceCheck.Results[0].SetRawValue(3.0); // boxes still

// 1. Runtime checks for SetRawValue
//serviceCheck.Results[0].SetRawValue(null); // throws  - non nullable double
//serviceCheck.Results[0].SetRawValue("not valid"); // would throw
//serviceCheck.Results[1].SetTypedValue<int>(3); // throws

//2. Compile time safety for assignment
if (serviceCheck.Results[1].Type == typeof(string)) {
    serviceCheck.Results[1].SetTypedValue("This is a test");
}

if (serviceCheck.Results[1] is IServiceCheckResult<string> cast) {
    cast.SetValue("This is also a test");
}

// same as before
serviceCheck.Results[2].SetRawValue(MyEnum.None);
serviceCheck.Results[3].SetRawValue(null);

foreach (var result in serviceCheck.Results) {
    if (result.Type == typeof(string)) {
        var getValue = result.GetTypedValue<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(getValue); // This is also a test
        result.SetTypedValue<string>(null); // change here to null
        // so we can fail validaiton
    }

    var rawValue = result.GetRawValue();
    var isValid = result.Validate();
    Console.WriteLine($"Validation for {result.GetType()} with value {rawValue ?? "null"} : {isValid}");
}

//Validation for ServiceCheckResult`1[System.Double] with value 3 : True
//This is also a test
//Validation for ServiceCheckResult`1[System.String] with value null : False
//Validation for ServiceCheckResult`1[MyEnum] with value None : False
//Validation for ServiceCheckResult`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Double]] with value null : False


I think one issue of this class is that you're letting caller accessing too many parts that should be private to the class, i.e. needs more abstractions. For example:
var serviceCheck = new ServiceCheck();

// implement different overloads for Validate() for compile-time safety
serviceCheck.Validate(1.0);
serviceCheck.Validate("This is a test");
serviceCheck.Validate(MyEnum.None); 

// instead of accessing the stored inputs in order to call Validate(),
// let ServiceCheck handle that, 
// so caller just gets all bool results and that's all it needs to know.
foreach (bool result in serviceCheck.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

ServiceCheck now needs to remember two things:

The inputs - 1.0, This is a test, MyEnum.None
The validators to be used

This can be make into another class specifically for inputs,
public class ServiceCheckInput<T> : IServiceCheckInput {
  T RawValue { get; init; }
  
  // note: IResultValidator now has generic types.
  IResultValidator<T> Validator { get; init; } 

  public bool Validate() {
      return this.Validator.Validate(RawValue);
  }

So the Validate() will do something like this:
public class ServiceCheck {
  private ICollection<IServiceCheckInput> Inputs = new();

  public IEnumerable<bool> Results => this.Inputs.Select(i => i.Validate());
  // ...

  public void Validate(string s)
  {
     var newInput = new ServiceCheckInput<string> {
       RawValue = s,
       Validator = new StringValidator();
     }
     this.Inputs.Add(newInput);
  }
}

And a StringValidator would look like:
public class StringValidator : IResultValidator<string>
{
    public bool Validate<string>(string? s) // implementing the interface
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
}

